# php date->diff() returning nonsensical amounts

Tags: php, datetime, laravel, datediff

This is my code:

```
$logdate = Input::get('logdate');
            $enddate = Input::get('enddate');
            //Cast the dates to yyyy-dd-mm format for comparison
            $startdt  = date('Y-d-m',strtotime($logdate));
            $enddt = date('Y-d-m',strtotime($enddate));
            //Cast the dates into datetime objects
            $date1 = new DateTime($startdt);
            $date2 = new DateTime($enddt);
            //Calculate the difference between the 2 datetime objects
            $diff = $date1->diff($date2, true);
            //cast logdate into correct format for entry in the database
            $newlogdate = strtotime($logdate);
            $formatlogdate = date('Y-d-m',$newlogdate);
```

I'm using this to get the amount of days in the interval:

```
 Log::info(intval($diff->days));
```

The code here works fine whenever I write code that involves 12 day differences or less withhin the same month but as soon as it's more than 12 days or as soon as I try to calculate differences between 2 months it goes haywire and gives me 16000+ as a result

for example according to this code the difference in days between 26/04/2015 and 02/05/2015 is 16557 days, I don't know how they get to this number but it's around 45 years, and the result is always 16000 + no matter which dates I pick given they are outside the 12 day single month radius

Comment: As you are working with Laravel it might be an idea to use Carbon. It's built in and saves you some lines of code. http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference

Comment: that's pretty nice, I wish I'd seen that before I wrote all the logic, no point in rewriting now as it works but thanks for the tip, I'll keep that saved in the back of my head for when I need to do something like this again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are doing - `date('Y-d-m',strtotime($logdate));` it is returning - `1970-01-01` for both the dates. 
`/` is creating the problem.
Try this -

```
$log = '26/04/2015';
$end = '02/05/2015';

$date1 = new DateTime(str_replace('/', '-', $log));
$date2 = new DateTime(str_replace('/', '-', $end));
$diff = $date1->diff($date2, true);
echo $diff->days;
```

**Output**

```
6
```

Comment: I am however getting a different problem now where if I try to create events in my database (which is why I needed the count for how many rows I should have), it returns 1970 every time now

Comment: Initial date: "$formatlogdate = date('Y-d-m',$newlogdate);"
every next date: "$nextdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($formatlogdate. ' + ' . $i . ' days'));" I need these dates in the format yyyy/mm/dd but as soon as I go outside of the same month it resets to 1970

Comment: I think I got it to work like this:$dateadded = $date1->add('P'.$i.'D');
                $nextdate = $dateadded->format('Y/m/d');

Comment: nope that's wrong it's ->add(new DateInterval('P1D'); appearantly

Answer (score 0):

The correct way for you to do this would be:-

```
$log = '26/04/2015';
$end = '02/05/2015';

$date1 = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $log);
$date2 = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $end);
$diff = $date1->diff($date2, true);
echo $diff->days;
```

http://3v4l.org/EhGaA

Answer (score 0):

Or try it:

```
$datetime1 = strtotime("2011-10-10 10:00:00");
$datetime2 = strtotime("2011-10-10 10:45:00");
$interval  = abs($datetime2 - $datetime1);
$minutes   = round($interval / 60);
echo 'Diff. in minutes is: '.$minutes;
```